# String Array. Select

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have the following string arrays:

```
var array1 = new String[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" }

var array2 = new String[] { "B", "D" }
```

I need to do the following:

1) Find the item in array2 which appears firts in array1 (In this case is B);

2) Get the item in (1) and all the others which appear after it in array1.

So in this case I would get:

```
var array3 = new String[] { "B", "C", "D" }
```

I was trying to do it, in one step, using a lambda expression.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: @Bridge - look below. People will help you anyway.

Comment: Sorry, for the delay ... I was away ...

Comment: This is what I ended up using: Int32 index = array2.Select(x => Array.IndexOf(array1, x)).Min();
var array3 = array1.Where(x => array1.IndexOf(array1, x) >= index).ToArray();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var array3 = array1.SkipWhile(x => !array2.Contains(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: That seems a great solution ... But sometimes I might need "B, C and D" in the list ... Other times I might need only "C and D". I forgot that detail ...

Comment: @Shapper Changing the rules after the game has started? `sometimes I might need "B, C and D" in the list ... Other times I might need only "C and D"` Or no rules?